# Will my iAds only start working after my app is on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, show, iad

So, all I need here is some clarification. What I've done is:

**a)** Added the iAds to my project. The test ad, with the blue background and the text saying "You're connected to iAd." It's showing up in my app correctly, but it doesn't have any real ads displaying, yet.

**b)** Next, what I did, was I went to iTunes Connect and set up all my taxes and certificates and bank information, and stuff. That's supposed to set up the real ads for me, right?

**c)** I do have a PAID Apple Developer Account, so I know that isn't the problem.

So, am I supposed to assume that it's working fine? Do the real ads only start showing once the app is submitted on the App Store? I think I remember reading so, somewhere on  apple.developer.com, but I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. What I DON'T want to happen, is that the app gets on the App Store, and the iAds aren't working properly. That would be disastrous.

Really, all I need is clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the real ads only start showing once the app is submitted on the
>   App Store?

After your application has been **approved** and **released** on the App Store it will be reviewed by the iAd Network team. Once they approve, ads will be delivered to your application.

If you're receiving the blue *You're Connected To iAd* advertisements when testing your application then you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I'm glad I thought smart and asked, though.